# How to get lastInsertID when executing a Stored Procedure on a mySQL Server in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

Method 1 works fine for a standard prepared Query (I believe that's what its called) but I can't get either method 2 or 3 to return a LastInsertID - similar but different and not sure of advantages of either.

My main thing at this stage is getting the LastInsertID when using a Stored Procedure.

MySQL Table

```
CREATE TABLE `forms` (
  `FORM_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `OUID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `OID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `UPDATED_DATE` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `FORM_JSON` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL CHECK (json_valid(`FORM_JSON`))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

MySQL Stored Procedure- for Methods 2 & 3

```
DROP PROCEDURE `FORM_SAVEAS`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `FORM_SAVEAS`
(IN `V_OUID` INT, IN `V_OID` INT, IN `V_FORM_JSON` JSON) 
NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER INSERT INTO `forms` 
(OUID ,OID ,FORM_JSON ) 
VALUEs (V_OUID ,V_OID ,V_FORM_JSON)
```

Method 1) Prepared statement(This Works - returns LastInsertID ok) - but I'd like to use a Stored Proc

```
<?php  

$V_OUID      = 1;
$V_OID       = 2;
$V_FORM_JSON = '{"var1":"data 1","var2":"Data two","var3":"DATA III"}';

include('database_connection.php');

$query = "INSERT INTO forms (OUID       , OID    , FORM_JSON) 
                     VALUES ($V_OUID    , $V_OID , '" . $V_FORM_JSON . "')";

echo "The Query : $query";
try{
  $DB_CON -> exec($query);
  $form_id = $DB_CON->lastInsertId();
  echo "New Record created Successfully ID is: " . $form_id;
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
  echo $query;
}
```

Method 2) This Inserts the data but doesn't return the `lastInsertId`

```
<?php  

$V_OUID      = 1;
$V_OID       = 2;
$V_FORM_JSON = '{"var1":"data 1","var2":"Data two","var3":"DATA III"}';

include('database_connection.php');

$query = "CALL FORM_SAVEAS($V_OUID    , $V_OID , '" . $V_FORM_JSON . "')";

echo "The Query : $query";
try{
  $DB_CON -> exec($query);
  $form_id = $DB_CON->lastInsertId();
  echo "New Record created Successfully ID is: " . $form_id;
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
  echo $query;
}


?>
```

Method 3) This also Inserts the data but doesn't return the `lastInsertId`

```
<?php  

$V_OUID      = 1;
$V_OID       = 2;
$V_FORM_JSON = '{"var1":"data 1","var2":"Data two","var3":"DATA III"}';

include('database_connection.php');

$statement = $DB_CON->prepare('CALL FORM_SAVEAS(:V_OUID,:V_OID,:V_FORM_JSON)');
$statement->bindParam(':V_OUID', $V_OUID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindParam(':V_OID', $V_OID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindParam(':V_FORM_JSON', $V_FORM_JSON, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->execute();
$form_id = $DB_CON->lastInsertID();

echo "New Record created Successfully ID is: " . $form_id;

?>
```

Of methods 2 & 3 which is best or is there a better way?

Comment: Methods #1 and #2 are extremely problematic because of SQL injection. The third one looks safe and should work.

Comment: @tadman - thanks for taking a look but it, #3, always returns Zero (0).. I read something about need to get ID before commit but I don't know how - any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure there's no errors or issues? What does `execute()` return?

Comment: execute just returns 0

Comment: That's a negative result, so it's likely the query failed for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

## It's a Solution but not a perfect answer

I'd liked to have used PDO `lastInsertID()`

Instead I've given the Stored Procedure an `OUT` Parameter which sends back the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` from mySQL... The Stored Procedure now looks like this.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `FORM_SAVEAS`
  (IN `V_OUID` INT, IN `V_OID` INT, IN `V_FORM_JSON` JSON, OUT `V_FORM_ID` INT(11)) 
  NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
  BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO `forms` (OUID ,OID ,FORM_JSON ) 
    VALUEs (V_OUID ,V_OID ,V_FORM_JSON);

    set V_FORM_ID := last_insert_id(); 
  END
```

The PHP became...

```
$statement = $DB_CON->prepare('CALL FORM_SAVEAS(:V_OUID,:V_OID,:V_FORM_JSON,@V_FORM_ID);');
$statement->bindParam(':V_OUID', $V_OUID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindParam(':V_OID', $V_OID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindParam(':V_FORM_JSON', $V_FORM_JSON, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->execute();
$statement->closeCursor();

// execute the second query to get result from the OUT parameter
$row = $DB_CON->query("SELECT @V_FORM_ID AS V_FORM_ID")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$V_FORM_ID = $row['V_FORM_ID'];

echo "New Record created Successfully ID is: " . $V_FORM_ID;
```

> NOTE all the additions to this code of V_FORM_ID that would have been
> unnecessary if PDO `lastInsertID` had worked.  I'd still be happy to know if it's a PDO bug or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Somehow, i really don't know why it return 0 except we call it within procedure it self, but thanks for your suggestion. it help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of confusing information on this subject throughout the Web.
To put it simply, in your stored procedure, after you have completed your insert query (into what we'll cal "YourTable"), end it with a semi-colon, then do a select on that table, with the following:

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS WhateverVariableYouChose
FROM YourTable;

That ID is then returned, just as any select. So, in your PHP, you simply do

$R = $stmt->fetch();
$LastInsert = $R[WhateverVariableYouChose];