# SQL Last Insert ID always return 0

Tags: mysql, database, go

```
query, err := dbSQL.Prepare(`
        INSERT INTO class (
            subject_id,
            class_name,
            createAt,
            updatedAt,
        )
        VALUES (?, ?, NOW(), NOW())
    `)

checkError(err)

result, err := query.Exec(
    subjectID,
    className,
)

checkError(err)

returnID, err := result.LastInsertId()

checkError(err)

dbSQL.Commit()
```

`returnID` always return 0

Note: my auto increment is disable.

Whats wrong? Is it because `dbSQL.Commit()` is below `result.LastInsertId()` or auto increment off making chaos?

Comment: *"With no argument, LAST_INSERT_ID() returns a BIGINT UNSIGNED (64-bit) value representing the first **automatically generated value successfully inserted for an AUTO_INCREMENT column** as a result of the most recently executed INSERT statement. "* -- If *no* value was generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column during the insert then LAST_INSERT_ID() will return 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was mentioned in [this thread](https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/lastinsertid-is-returning-0-when-using-database-sql-package-with-oracle-driver/10385), with, as advice:

> It is better idea to use an SP and in this SP return the last id

(SP: Stored Procedure)
[Example in Go](https://gist.github.com/cbess/d14f8ec78bf239b72645246c9ee3f67b).

Example: "[How to get `lastInsertID` when executing a Stored Procedure on a mySQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62793474/6309)"

That would be safer than relying on a direct call, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/289916/6309).